# Delete favicon.ico file from blogger

Tags: javascript, blogger, favicon

I replaced the favicon of in my web page with the one I wanted giving reference to another page that has saved the file. But despite that works and the favicon is displayed, the website also charges the old file, which I do not want because the presence of the old file causes conflicts with the SSL certificate that I installed.

My question is: How can I remove old resident .ico file in my domain if Blogger does not allow me the option to completely remove it?

PS: Neither I can not remove the reference to the old file in the code because it does not appear explicitly but rather with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally get an answer for my question. Just is deleting this line code on the template:

```
<b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>
```

Maybe deletes RSS reference but do you can copy it from the code before deleting the line mentioned, pressing Ctrl + U in the website and then pasting it on the template.